# Which is Windows 7 most similar to?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-vista, virtual-machine, vmware-server

Is Windows 7 more similar to Windows XP or Windows Vista? I'm trying to create a Virtual Machine for Windows 7 in VMWare Server and it doesn't show Windows 7 as an option. It only has Windows XP and Windows Vista.

Comment: So basically you've never used 7 at all?  As the answers suggest, under the hood it's very close to Vista...but ABOVE THE HOOD it's also very close to Vista.  I don't see how you'd think otherwise if you had used it...and you should use it because it's pretty awesome.  Give it a shot sometime!

Comment: I already used it. Ubuntu is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on what you mean by "most similar to", but your best bet is probably Windows Vista (if, [as CPlumley recommends](https://superuser.com/questions/172210/which-is-windows-7-most-similar-to/172213#172213), you can't choose a later version of Windows Server, such as 2008) for these reasons, to name a few:

1. Windows Vista and Windows 7 are actually under the same major release numeber (Vista being  6.0 and 7 being 6.1)
2. Windows Vista and Windows 7 share the same Desktop Window Manager ([aero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Aero))
3. Both environments share hardware and software compatibility (Windows 7 drivers usually work with Windows Vista, where they may not with Windows XP or earlier)

Comment: I will just add that while Windows Vista and Windows 7 share the same Desktop Manager, Windows Vista is version WDDM 1 and Windows 7 is WDDM 1.1. Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Display_Driver_Model#WDDM_1.1

Answer (score 3):

It's closer to Vista. Here's a [guide](http://www.petri.co.il/installing-windows-7-in-vmware-server-20.htm) I found but while targeted at the beta version of Windows 7 it should still be relevant. The guide suggests selecting Server 2008, which is built off of Vista.